System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web
I am upgrading a multi-project solution in visual studio from .net 4.8 framework at .net 8. I am running into this issue with a test:
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)

This is the test:
using AutoFixture;
using FluentAssertions;
using Orleans.TestingHost;
using SepsisServer.Services.Interfaces.Grains;
using SepsisServer.Test.Common.AutoFixture;
using Xunit;

namespace SepsisServer.Test.Unit.Services.Orleans
{
    [Collection(ClusterCollection.Name)]
    public class PatientProcessingGrainFixture : FixtureBase
    {
        private readonly TestCluster cluster;

        public PatientProcessingGrainFixture(OrleansFixtureBase fixture)
         {
             cluster = fixture.Cluster;
         }

         [Fact]
         public void PatientProcessingGrain_ShouldNotThrowException_WhenCalled()
         {
             var siteId = AutoFixture.Create<int>();
             var patientId = AutoFixture.Create<int>();
             var grainId = AutoFixture.Create<string>();
             var grain = cluster.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IPatientProcessingGrain>(grainId);
        
             Invoking(() => grain.ProcessPatient(siteId, patientId)).Should().NotThrow();
         }
     }
 }

I am unfamiliar with navigating .net8 and the different type / version requirements. I am not sure what is the problem with this assembly, why vs cant find it or how to add it or change it to work in .net8.
I think the issue may be that the 'PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' doesn't exist in .net core, but I dont know how to find where its being referenced or remove it.
Any suggestions would be really greatly appreciated, ese]pecially if there are any reccomendations of other ways to do/replace this in .net8. Thank you everyone for your time!

Can you please share [mre]? Or at least your .csproj file? Sounds like you have dependencies mixed up since System.Web is mostly used for older framework AFAIK (and PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute is part of the ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core).

@GuruStron yes I can! What is the best way for me to share that adding screenshots of the csproj file? Whats the best way to provide a minimal reproducible example?

It depends on the size of the [mre]. Ideally you should add it to the post. If it is too big then you can try sharing it via something like github (though it is against the rules AFAIK, but still).

@GuruStron but do you mean through images / text I should give an example of something someone else could copy and run on their own?

Do not post images. Ideally you should post something which can be easily copy-pasted and run to repro the issue. It is not always possible so you can post only relevant parts + full repro somewhere like github
